# Парсинг содержимого <ul></ul> веб страницы

Tags: python, python-3.x, requests, beautiful-soup, bs4

Стоит задача пропарсить сайт и достать из него изображения.

Использую библиотеки `requests` и `BeautifulSoup`.

Проблема в том, что когда я делаю парсинг сайта напрямую, то  BeautifulSoup не хочет отображать  содержимое  списка в котором находятся изображения. Суп показывает, что в списке нет элементов. Есть подозрение, что они подгружаются отдельно, потому что если страницу сохранить на ПК и парсить как  локальный файл, то Суп прекрасно находит содержимое списка.

Вопрос в том, как мне все-таки получить содержимое этих списков. Какова технология их получения и какой (какими) библиотеками надо воспользоваться. Спасибо!

Вот этот ресурс: (http://gepur.ru), к примеру картинки с этой  страницы: (http://gepur.ru/product/plate-6916). Спасибо!

Comment: Желательно все же указать ресурс, который вы хотите спарсить

Comment: А вы не через браузер качайте, а через requests и смотрите что пришло. А также используйте инспектор вашего браузера для просмотра структуры страницы и запросов на ней (обычно это вкладка Сети)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В ходе изучения запросов и поиска внутри страницы я узнал что список картинок находится внутри страницы, но как объект `Javascript`, а не как тег `HTML`, но его очень просто получить, для этого используется простенькая регулярка и парсер `JSON`.

Привожу весь рабочий код:

```
import json
import re
import sys

from urllib.parse import urljoin

import requests

rs = requests.get('http://gepur.ru/product/plate-6916')
html = rs.text

# Ищем строку c описанием модели
match = re.search(r'ProductPage\.init\((.+)\)', html)
if not match:
    print('Не получилось вытащить описание модели')
    sys.exit()

# Вытаскиваем объект js из параметра функции init
json_text = match.group(1)

# Парсим его как JSON
json_data = json.loads(json_text)

# Вытаскиваем список ссылок на картинки
for url_img_rel in json_data['getImages']['originImg']:
    url_img = urljoin('http://gepur.ru', url_img_rel)
    print(url_img)
```

Консоль:

```
http://gepur.ru/products/10000/6916/simple/origins/6916_1.jpg
http://gepur.ru/products/10000/6916/simple/origins/6916_2.jpg
http://gepur.ru/products/10000/6916/simple/origins/6916_3.jpg
```

А для http://gepur.ru/product/plate-6917 в консоли будет:

```
http://gepur.ru/products/10000/6917/simple/origins/6917_1.jpg
http://gepur.ru/products/10000/6917/simple/origins/6917_2.jpg
http://gepur.ru/products/10000/6917/simple/origins/6917_3.jpg
http://gepur.ru/products/10000/6917/simple/origins/6917_4.jpg
http://gepur.ru/products/10000/6917/simple/origins/6917_5.jpg
http://gepur.ru/products/10000/6917/simple/origins/6917_6.jpg
```

---

Есть еще один способ их получить, судя по запросам, нужно после прогрузки в рамке текущей сессии отправить POST запрос на http://gepur.ru/ajax/last-viewed и вернется JSON, похожий на тот, что был на самой странице при ее загрузке (непонятно даже зачем такое сделали, ведь данные уже есть).

Код будет такой:

```
import requests
session = requests.session()

# Нам нужны куки чтобы второй запрос был удачным
rs = session.get('http://gepur.ru/product/plate-6917')
print(rs)

rs = session.post('http://gepur.ru/ajax/last-viewed', headers={'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'})
print(rs)

# Текст нужно распарсить модулем json как сделано в примере выше
print(rs.text)
```

Comment: Уважаемый gil9red! Огромное спасибо! На такой развернутый ответ я даже не мог надеяться! Очень помогли!!!

Comment: @Владимир, парсинг на питоне -- мое любимое дело, вот и не смог пройти мимо :) А благодарность на этом сайте выражается через плюс и галочку слева от моего ответа ;)